# How is a quartz watch tunning fork cut so precise as to be exactly a power of 2?

Tags: resonance

Maybe out of scope for physics, maybe a gemology or electrical engineering community question. Sorry not sure where to go with it. Have to start somewhere.

A quartz watch tunning fork viabrates at 32,768 cycles . How is it manufactured to be exactly a power of 2?

Comment: It’s not exactly a power of 2. It’s somewhere between 32767.5 and 32768.5. Does that seem easier to manufacture?

Comment: There manufactured using many of the same ideas you would use to make a music tuning fork. Namely given a material it is just a matter of making the tuning fork the right shape  and weight

Comment: @shai horowitz....since posting this i found some Army Training Films circa 1940 that shows  how quartz is cut to create desired frequency. They used it for radio tuning and broadcasting. I have to finish viewing it.

Comment: Could you post that link?

Comment: Probably the same way they manufacture it to be any other number of cycles: they just make it a certain size and shape

Comment: @user253751...yah...apparently that's about all there is to it.  What's remarkable is the property of the quartz to be all things to all of man's needs.. you can carve it and shape it to be any animal you want.